# retrieve multiple columns within collection using simple form and pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

The idea is to display a collection of records with checkboxes, but also I would like to retrieve multiple columns for each record. I know the `pluck` method can retrieve multiple columns, however, simple form does not display them. So my code looks like:

```
<%= f.association :option, collection: @question.option.pluck(:lead, :description), as: :check_boxes %>
```

But in my view, only the `:lead` column is displayed?

Comment: Use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`

Comment: no, that's not the issue (I'll correct my question). The issue is, only :lead is displayed, where I would expect :lead :comment, since those are the columns plucked.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: `:lead` is the value displayed, and `:description` is the field value, probably. Can you post the resulting HTML of this code?

Comment: Rails 5.0.0.1

the exact code:
`<%= f.association :option, collection: @scan_element.disk_element.option.pluck(:lead, :value), as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false %>`

Comment: this returns
` <div class="form-group check_boxes optional scan_element_option"><label class="control-label check_boxes optional">Option</label><span class="checkbox"><label for="scan_element_option_id_2"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="2" name="scan_element[option_id][]" id="scan_element_option_id_2" />two_label</label></span>,

Comment: `<%= f.association :option, collection: @scan_element.disk_element.option.pluck(:value, :lead, :description), as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false %>`

 returns:

Comment: <div class="form-group check_boxes optional scan_element_option"><label class="control-label check_boxes optional">Option</label><span class="checkbox"><label for="scan_element_option_id_two_label"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="two_label" name="scan_element[option_id][]" id="scan_element_option_id_two_label" /></label></span>

Answer (score 0):

After some trial/errors this gives me exactly what I want:

```
<%= f.association :option, collection: @scan_element.disk_element.option, label_method: :option_label, as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false %>
```

and in the Option model:

```
def option_label
  "#{self.value.to_s}  #{self.lead}: #{self.description}"
end
```

html returns:

```
<div class="form-group check_boxes optional scan_element_option"><label class="control-label check_boxes optional">Option</label><span class="checkbox"><label for="scan_element_option_id_19"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="19" name="scan_element[option_id][]" id="scan_element_option_id_19" />0  zero_label: zero description</label></span>
```